# Quick Search Box to filter adapter

Tags: android, search, filter

Right now I have a list activity powered by a cursor adapter.
I have a AutoCompleteTextView that allows the user to filter the list.
Code looks like this:

```
filterText = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.search_box);
filterText.setAdapter(mAdapter);
filterText.setDropDownHeight(0); // hide the drop down, just filter the listActivity
filterText.setThreshold(1);
```

It works great. I want to switch to the Quick Search Box so I don't take up so much screen space and I feel like the Quick Search Box is more UI standard.
The problem is the Quick Search Box doesn't really filter a list very well. It doesn't broadcast the intent on every letter typed (only when you click the search button). Is there a good tutorial on how to do this somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to stick with the filter text and now worry about the Quick Search Box.
`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` was very helpful in making the decision